# Вывести число без округления

Tags: java

Программа выводит корни квадратного уравнения:

```
System.out.printf(Locale.US, "%.4f %.4f", x2,x1);
```

Кроме простого вывода она еще и округляет число с точностью до `10^-4`. Но мне нужно именно "с точностью", т.е. БЕЗ ОКРУГЛЕНИЯ. Как это сделать?

Comment: Вы уже сделали что спрашиваете, что не устраивает-то?

Comment: @klopp, паттерн `%.4f` округляет (*round*) значение до 4х знаков, а ТС хочет обрезать его (*truncate*) до 4х знаков.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Прям printf() из Си. Тут суть в строчке %.4f %.4f", .4f и определяет вывод числа float с точностью 4 знаков после запятой. Уберите или поставьте нужное количество знаков

Comment: Вы меня не поняли. 4f (округление до 4 знаков после запятой, как я понял). Мне же нужно НЕ ОКРУГЛЕНИЕ, а, как сказать то.. "обрубление" по 4 знакам после запятой

Comment: Может, глупость скажу, но первое что мне сейчас приходит в голову - взять от вашего числа String и отсечь ненужные символы после запятой

Answer (score 3):

Вам нужно округление вниз.

```
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.0000");
df.setRoundingMode(RoundingMode.DOWN);
System.out.println(df.format(12.49688f));
System.out.println(df.format(12.456));
System.out.println(df.format(12.0));
```

выведет

```
2.4968
12.456
12
```

Answer (score 1):

Есть еще способ хак:

1. Сначала округляем до 5-ти цифр после запятой
2. Потом отбрасываем последнюю значащую цифру